# Syntax help with echo html and variables

Tags: php, html, variables, syntax

I have this code (see below) that I'm having trouble echoing the variables out. On the 5th line is an echo, within that echo is a load of html (which I've escaped the quotation marks) and a load of variables. I can't get the variables to echo out within the main echo.

Update:
Also within there is an onclick that needs to be taken into account.

```
<?php
   if(
       in_array("Branding", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding"
   ){
     echo "
        <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"<?php echo $fields->thumb_image; ?>\" alt=\"<?php echo $fields->company_name; ?>\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2><?php echo $fields->company_name; ?></h2>
                <h3><?php echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));?></h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4><?php echo $fields->project_name; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $fields->description; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2><?php echo $fields->company_name; ?></h2>
                <h3><?php echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));?></h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
     ";
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use echo within an echo, you just need to concatenate your strings properly like so:

```
     $Content =  "
        <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='" . get_page_link($post->ID). "';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"" . $fields->thumb_image . "\" alt=\"" . $fields->company_name. "\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2> " . $fields->company_name . "</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')) . "</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4>" . $fields->project_name . "</h4>
                <p>" . $fields->description . "</p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2>" . $fields->company_name . "</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')). "</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>";
  echo $Content;
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a little misunderstanding here.

In PHP you can output HTML either by

- writing simple HTML outside `<?php...?>`, and possibly inserting some PHP code inside
- using something like `echo` / `print` to output a [PHP string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) which includes HTML

But you cannot mix up the two.

So this is not good:

```
echo "... src=\"<?php echo $fields->thumb_image; ?>\" ...";
```

Because this is a string, and in a string you can not open a `<?php` section. You should do something like this instead:

```
echo "... src=\"{$fields->thumb_image}\" ...";
```

which is one of the cool ways to insert PHP variables inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
echo " ... <?php ... ?> ...";
```

will not work.

Instead you could "break in and out" of php, like:

```
...
?>
<div class="grid-box" onclick="location.href='<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>';" style="cursor: pointer;">
<div class="phase-1"> ... <?php
```

Or use s/printf

```
printf(
    '<div class="grid-box" onclick="location.href='%s';" style="cursor: pointer;">',
    get_page_link($post->ID)
);
```

Or use string concatenation:

```
echo "html ...", get_page_link($post->ID), "some more html...";
```

Or use some kind of templating code.

Comment: +1 for the several nice ways of doing the same (`printf` is great)

Answer (score 0):

Just close the php tag after the if and open it before the closing semi-colon.

```
if(
       in_array("Branding", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding"
   ){
   ?>
        <div class="grid-box" onclick="location.href='<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>';" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class="phase-1">
           <img class="grid-image" src="<?php echo $fields->thumb_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fields->company_name; ?>" height="152" width="210" />
           <div class="grid-heading">
                <h2><?php echo $fields->company_name; ?></h2>
                <h3><?php echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));?></h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="phase-2">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h4><?php echo $fields->project_name; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $fields->description; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-heading-hover">
                <h2><?php echo $fields->company_name; ?></h2>
                <h3><?php echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));?></h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```